Proof that four players playing all doubles matches will either have an ultimate winner or ultimate loser
Four players are playing a table tennis tournament. Three games are played, one for each of the possible doubles (2 vs 2) matches. Every game has a winner, there are no ties. I'm looking for a "nice" proof that either one player wins all their games, or one player loses all their games. The "nicest" proof I can do is below, but is there a shorter way to prove it, without having to break the tournament down into the possible games so much?
Suppose, for a contradiction, that no player wins 3 or 0 matches. Each match has two winners, so the total number of wins is 6. Each of the 4 players has at least 1 win, and no player has 3 wins, so the distribution of wins must be $(2, 2, 1, 1)$. Let $A, B$ be the players with 2 wins and $C, D$ the players with 1 win. When $A, B$ play together on a team, they must win, because otherwise they both have to win their remaining two games but also play against each other in both of them. So WLOG let the first game be $(A, B)$ vs $(C, D)$ with a win for $(A, B)$. WLOG let $A$ win game two and $B$ win game three. But $A$'s partner in game two (call them $x$) is also $B$'s partner in game three, because after the first two games $x$ and $B$ have never been a team. And so $x$ also wins two games, so the distribution of wins is in fact $(2, 2, 2, 0)$ [or $(2, 2, 0, 2)$], which gives us a contradiction.

You can do a nice diagram with Edges and Vertices (graph theory style)


Each black dot represents a person.

A blue line drawn between any two dots means when those two players played together, they won. A red line joining two dots means that pair lost.
We start with one pair winning and therefore the other pair lost (it doesn't matter which).


Next, the top left person must have played with the bottom left person. Suppose that that pair won. (If the other pair won then the whole thing is similar).
Up to this point, we must have a pair of adjacent blue edges and a pair of adjacent red edges.


Finally, the diagonals must play. In this example, we see that either the top left wins all his games (top left to bottom right edge is blue), or the bottom right lost all his games (top left to bottom right edge is red).

Maybe this is simpler:  In the first game, renaming the players if necessary, AB beat CD.  The second game has AC vs BD and we can assume AC win.  A now has 2 wins and D has 0 wins.  The third game has AD vs BC.  If AD win A has 3 wins while if AD lose D has no wins.

$+1$.  Similar to "The winning partners of the first game  play against each other in the second, as do the losing partners of the first game. So after the second game someone must have won two and someone else must have lost two, and they must be partners in the third.  So after the third, one of these two will satisfy the requirements."
